# How to backup Linode configuration

Tags: ubuntu, backup, linode, sysadmin

I have setup LEMP on Ubuntu 18.04 Linode.
I have configured all my required settings for my laravel app.

1. Can someone advise how to backup these settings so that I can use the same settings for another linode setup.
2. Also I need advise if there is anyother way to setup a secure LEMP install without manually starting from scratch in my SSH

NB: I know that another linode can just be spinned off the existing linode. I just need to rebuild another linode with the configs I am satisfied with.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start in the other end of the problem: Use Ansible or some other tool to programmatically define a working system, and then you have the ability to roll out new systems from a playbook that can be version controlled in something like gitlab or github.

Linode has some guides to get you started in their environment: https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/configuration-management/getting-started-with-ansible/